# What could be the opposite of (online) live teaching?

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for an opposite of "live online teaching". Live online teaching would be for instance a lesson that is taught via [Skype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype).

On the opposite side, you could record a video of you teaching something and make it available for viewing and/or download. Only in this case the teaching is not "live". Note that I am still considering this method to be "online" in the sense that you access the contents online (as opposed to face-to-face, classroom teaching or learning from a book). I guess what I'm looking for is an opposite of "live", applied to this context.

Comment: Maybe archived? It's commonly used in regards to online resources.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. It's not too bad but perhaps it sounds like the contents are no longer available?

Comment: It does somewhat suggest the content is immutable or sealed, but not unavailable. Synonyms: stashed, recorded, aggregated, listed, registered.

Comment: I like both non-live (why didn't I think of it :) ) and recorded. Thanks !

Comment: @ermanen **ಠ_ಠ**

Comment: offline dead non-teaching?

Comment: Would offline cadaver slacking qualify?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the term "pre-recorded" which implies that the lessons have been recorded for later viewing but can still be viewed at any time.

Comment: Pre-recorded sounds as though it's recorded before it's recorded. I would think recorded is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

A recorded lecture or educational video is just an **instructional video**

Answer (score 2):

Consider *canned* or [pre-canned](http://jeronline.com/press/clientsask.pdf).

> [**canned**](http://onlinedictionary.datasegment.com/word/canned): recorded; in contrast with live.
>
> [**canned**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canned): prepared or recorded at an earlier time for use in television, radio, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of (online) ***live teaching*** is ***Programmed Instruction***.

A distinction should be made between the event and how the event is diffused.

Let us ignore the *kind* of "teaching" for the moment. (PowerPoint Lecture vs. Workshop vs. Seminar)

An event that is diffused by some means as it is taking place can be said to be a live performance (live). An audience attendee with some smart device and a Skype, say, account could ***send*** it to a third party. The third party would be viewing the event live, diffused by Internet (online).

Right next to that individual is sitting another person with a smart device to *record* the event as it takes place. That file can be diffused by Internet to an enterprise that will store it for a person who will download it for view. Such is the case with "Podcasts."

The file can be viewed while held in a "cloud" online as with Vimeo or YouTube.

If not live, that any existing event has been recorded is implicit.

That leaves an event not online and not live.

Programmed Instruction is student-centred/student-driven and is not live as there is no need for it to be. Programmed instruction online is optimal; but, not necessary for acceptable results.

I submit therefore that the diametric ***opposite of (online) live teaching is Programmed Instruction***.

Answer (score 0):

How about [evergreen content](https://www.google.com/search?&q=evergreen%20content)?  Otherwise I agree with **pre-recorded**.  A less elegant but also descriptive is **always-available**.

Answer (score 0):

The word I used in my online classes is **asynchronous**. This applies to any aspect of an online class that can happen at the students' convenience: discussion message boards vs live chat, tests that can be completed at any time within a broad window, etc.

Compare this usage to the fairly technical telecommunications definition:

> 2. of, used in, or being digital communication (as between computers) in which there is no timing requirement for transmission and in which
>      the start of each character is individually signaled by the
>      transmitting device ([Merriam Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/asynchronous))

So your non-live online teaching might be an asynchronous lecture (note that this could apply to, for example, a narrated PowerPoint presentation as well as a video of you lecturing), an asynchronous discussion, etc.